# Read the number of rows in a range with xlrd - Python

Tags: python, xlrd

I want to read the number of rows within a range. I have a file that has a lot of rows. I want to know the number of rows in a column range, let´s say, from column A through D.

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet.nrows[0:4] #I want to know the number of rows within that range, or "A{}:D{}"
```

If anyone knows a method to do this, please help me. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Iterate through columns...
Use loop:

```
for col_idx in range(0, num_cols):  # Iterate through columns 
        cell_obj = xl_sheet.cell(row_idx, col_idx)  # Get cell object by row, col
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything wrong with using xlrd, it's what I used first as well. However, I recommend using the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library, as it's much more used throughout the python community.

```
import pandas

dataframe = pandas.read_excel(file, usecols='A:D')
print(len(dataframe))
```

Comment: Thank you! didn't know that. The syntaxis looks better and easier for Data manipulation.